# How put button into variable when it appears after page onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

How can I get the button `add__deal__btn` after it appears?  When the page loads `add__deal__btn` doesn't exist, but after I add the `task__card` to the div it appears. How can I manipulate the button after it appears?

```js
let addTitle = document.querySelector('.add__title');
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.add__btn');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let addDealBtn = [];

addBtn.onclick = function() {
  let task = document.createElement('div');
  task.className = 'task__card';
  let taskTitle = document.createElement("h4");
  taskTitle.innerHTML = addTitle.value
  task.appendChild(taskTitle)
  addDealBtn = document.createElement("button");
  addDealBtn.className = "add__deal__btn";
  addDealBtn.innerHTML = "Add deal";
  task.appendChild(addDealBtn);
  tasks.append(task);
}

//THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK

addDeal = document.querySelectorAll('.add__deal__btn'); 

for(let i = 0;i<addDeal.length;i++){
 addDeal[i].onclick= function(){ 
   alert();
 } 
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <input type="text" class="add__title">
  <br>
  <button class="add__btn">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="tasks"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: `addDealBtn = document.createElement("button");` is already putting the button into a variable. You could just add it to the list of buttons using `addDeal.push(addDealBtn)` right after creating it. You could also assign the `addDealBtn.onclick = function() { ... }` when you create that button too...

Answer (score 1):

Add the onclick event when you create the button.

```js
let addTitle = document.querySelector('.add__title');
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.add__btn');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
let addDealBtn = [];

addBtn.onclick = function() {
  let task = document.createElement('div');
  task.className = 'task__card';
  let taskTitle = document.createElement("h4");
  taskTitle.innerHTML = addTitle.value
  task.appendChild(taskTitle)
  addDealBtn = document.createElement("button");
  addDealBtn.className = "add__deal__btn";
  addDealBtn.innerHTML = "Add deal";
  // Add onclick event here
  addDealBtn.onclick = function() {
      alert('Button clicked!');
  };
  task.appendChild(addDealBtn);
  tasks.append(task);
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <input type="text" class="add__title">
  <br>
  <button class="add__btn">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="tasks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `addDeal = document.querySelectorAll('.add__deal__btn');` only runs once (when the script loads). At that time, no `<button>` elements with class `add__deal__btn` exist in the DOM.

To achieve what you want simply add the event listener to each newly generated button. Like this:

```js
let addTitle = document.querySelector('.add__title');
let addBtn = document.querySelector('.add__btn');
let tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');

addBtn.onclick = function () {
  let task = document.createElement('div');
  task.className = 'task__card';
  let taskTitle = document.createElement("h4");
  taskTitle.innerText = addTitle.value;
  task.appendChild(taskTitle);
  let addDealBtn = document.createElement("button");
  addDealBtn.className = "add__deal__btn";
  addDealBtn.innerText = "Add deal";
  task.appendChild(addDealBtn);
  tasks.append(task);
  addDealBtn.onclick = function() {
    alert('Hey it works!');
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <input type="text" class="add__title">
  <br>
  <button class="add__btn">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="tasks"></div>
```

Tip: You don't need to create an array to store each new button you create anymore.